# iOS Keyboard Making View Disappear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimation, ios-keyboard-extension

I am having a bit of an issue here. I have my main view for my application, for different windows. I have put them off the view sight and they're animated to move into view when they are required, I have never had an issue with this before until I decided to create a text field. When I click the button to bring the view into show it appears, but when I click the text field to type and the keyboard loads the view disappears, but if I click the button to bring the view back the text field will be entered and ready to type. Anyone got any solutions? I am attaching the code below of the way the view is appearing.

Thanks,

CurtisB

```
- (IBAction)login:(id)sender {

    sidebutton = @"0";
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.0];
    [self.blackhide setFrame:CGRectMake(self.blackhide.frame.origin.x -750, self.blackhide.frame.origin.y, self.blackhide.frame.size.width, self.blackhide.frame.size.height)];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [self.button2 setFrame:CGRectMake(self.button2.frame.origin.x - 300, self.button2.frame.origin.y, self.button2.frame.size.width, self.button2.frame.size.height)];
    [self.mainview setFrame:CGRectMake(self.mainview.frame.origin.x - 300, self.mainview.frame.origin.y, self.mainview.frame.size.width, self.mainview.frame.size.height)];
    [self.sidebarview setFrame:CGRectMake(self.sidebarview.frame.origin.x - 376, self.sidebarview.frame.origin.y, self.sidebarview.frame.size.width, self.sidebarview.frame.size.height)];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.0];
    [self.loginview setFrame:CGRectMake(self.loginview.frame.origin.x + 376, self.loginview.frame.origin.y, self.loginview.frame.size.width, self.loginview.frame.size.height)];  
}
```

Comment: Put some more code i.e. what you are doing with textfield

Comment: block. based. animation. since. iOS4. please. thank. you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to bring the `subview` you want at the top to front by using following code:

```
[parentView bringSubviewToFront:childView];
```

For example, if you want to show `VIEW_A`, do that code whenever you are un-hiding that view. If still you get that issue, put that code when keyboard appears i.e. in `UITextfield` delegate method..

Add comment if you are still stuck..

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be the best solution.